# ITMS-90842: Invalid SDK usage with AppClip and Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, testflight, apple-appclips

Until I upload myapp to appstore
I have this issue:

```
Please correct the following issues, then upload again.

ITMS-90842: Invalid SDK usage - App clip 
'Runner.app/AppClips/RunnerAppClip.app' uses the SDK selector 
'requestAlwaysAuthorization', which is not supported. Ensure your app clip is 
using supported SDK features.
```

I am used location permission but how exclude specific location from AppClip

Answer (score 0):

You can include/exclude specific lines of code from your App Clip target using a Swift Compilation Flag.

To do this you can open the Build Settings of your App Clip target and add some custom flag like APPCLIP.

Then in your code...

```swift
#if !APPCLIP
//Location code that uses `requestAlwaysAuthorization`
#endif
```